# Remote queue-like auditing service ("append-only pastebin")

Tags: security, configuration, remote, readonly, audit

I am looking for an existing service / tool which would support the
following in a UNIX-like shell environment:

1. append-only writes, with writes guaranteed to be persistent for some *well-specified period* of time
2. command-line interface or possibility of sending request using common tools like `wget`/`curl`, `ssh`, `git` etc.
3. authentication-free (this would definitely simplify the previous item)

By design, such a service would be useful as a **tamper-free short-term
auditing system / tool**:

- *automated asymmetric encryption* of sensitive data (passphrase is not used in asymmetric encryption)
- no way to delete traces for a *guaranteed* period of time (e.g., 1 week)

Some use cases like

- automatically track the location of a protable computer or
- dump system log entries of interest

could easily be supported by writing to such an "append-only" service
from the from `/etc/rc.d/` startup script or from `(ana)cron`,
respectively. If an attacker steals the computer and boots the OS (the
former), or hacks into it (the latter), the user would be able to
detect it, perhaps with some help of yet another monitoring service
that reads the former append-only write service. (Note the attacker
could not delete the entries as it's "append-only" storage).

---

Current attempts of emulating such a service:

1. `ssh 'bash -c "cat ... >> writes.$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"'`

   Problem: requires a trusted machine (and do-it-yourself data cleanup)
2. Create a new anonymous pastebin.com document on each write. Not feasible:

   - No tamper-free storage of the *URL to each document*
     is not feasible (note editing or reusing the same one would allow
     deletion)
   - probable *IP ban* if writes are too frequent
3. Using a cloud-based file-management service, such as Dropbox

   - Create a Dropbox account associated with the `root`
   - Fetch Dropbox credentials via `ssh`/`scp` from a trusted
     machine/server, while making sure they don't escape the RAM (use
     `/run/shm/` to store them if necessary)
   - Delete contents of a well-known file, then rewrite new data.

   Problems:

   - tricky to set up in a *secure* way.
   - to read anything except the last written entry, one would need to
     *(manually) dig* through event history of file content updates.
4. Version Control System with no history rewrites, such as Mercurial

   Problem: storage is *bounded* - cleanup of old entries not possible (not deletion and recretion would make the service unavailable a that period of time)

Any ideas of how to support/implement such a service are appreciated.

Comment: [tarsnap](http://www.tarsnap.com/)

Comment: @mikeserv : Would you mind briefly explaning how does that tool solve each of the *limitations* outlined above? Thanks